# How to parse PHP Error Log?

Tags: php, parsing, error-handling

Well, I was trying to parse the PHP Error Log. Hence I built the following class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: toton
 * Date: 2/29/2016
 * Time: 8:16 AM
 */
final class error_parser
{
    private $log_file_path;
    private $current_line;
    private $recent;

    /**
     * error_parser constructor.
     * Takes in the path of the error log file of PHP ERROR LOG FILE.
     * And another param for checking to get the direction to traverse the file.
     * @param string $log_file_path
     * @param bool $recent
     */
    public function __construct($log_file_path, $recent = true)
    {
        $this->log_file_path = $log_file_path;
        $this->recent = $recent;
        $this->_parse();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Parses the PHP ERROR LOG, and pushes an array with the following structure:
     * array(
     * "date" => {DATE},
     * "severity" => {SEVERITY},
     * "message" => {message},
     * "stack_trace" => array(each({STACK_TRACE})) || false;
     * );
     * to the main array.
     * !!!! IMPORTANT !!!!
     * STACK TRACE IS NOT SUPPORTED AT THIS MOMENT
     * TODO: IMPLEMENT STACK TRACE
     * MILESTONE: NEXT_MAJOR RELEASE
     */
    private function _parse() {
        $contents = file_get_contents($this->log_file_path);
        if(!$contents){
            throw new Exception("Log file does not exist.", 2);
        }
        $lines = explode("\n", $contents);
        if($this->recent) {
            $lines = array_reverse($lines);
        }
        for($this->current_line = 0; $this->current_line < count($lines); $this->current_line++) {
            parse_loop:
            $current_line = trim($lines[$this->current_line]);
            if(strlen($current_line) == 0) {
                //If the line is empty throw it to the dustbin.
                // SORRY, FOR THE GOTO.
                // GOD PLEASE FORGIVE ME!
                $this->current_line = $this->current_line + 1;
                goto parse_loop;
            }
            if($current_line[0] != "[") {
                // NOT SUPPORTING STACK TRACES AT THE MOMENT
                $this->current_line = $this->current_line + 1;
                goto parse_loop;
            }
            $dateArr = array();
            preg_match('~^\[(.*?)\]~', $current_line, $dateArr);
            $date = array(
                "date" => explode(" ", $dateArr[1])[0],
                "time" => explode(" ", $dateArr[1])[1]
            );
            $severity = "";
            if(strpos($current_line, "PHP Warning")) {
                $severity = "WARNING";
            } elseif(strpos($current_line, "PHP Notice")) {
                $severity = "NOTICE";
            } elseif(strpos($current_line, "PHP Fatal error")) {
                $severity = "FATAL";
            } elseif(strpos($current_line, "PHP Parse error")) {
                $severity = "SYNTAX_ERROR";
            } else {
                $severity = "UNIDENTIFIED_ERROR";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Well, there maybe some bad-practises there in the code :-P)

One error for example could be this - `[28-Dec-2015 07:51:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pspell.dll' - The specified module could not be found.`

Anyway, I was able to extract the date and the type of the error. But I cannot find a way to parse the error message.

So my question is, how do I parse the error message out of the PHP Error Log?

Thanks in Advance, Cheers!

Comment: Why dou you need parsing PHP's error file? To find your code's problem? You can always set your own error and excepion handler, and it is a preferred way you know.

Comment: No, I was building a Admin Dashboard for my site and I just want a web interface to monitor my error logs.

Comment: that's what I thought. You need to build your own error handlers for that, you could save those errors in DB or file, in the format you want. I am going to post a simple solution, you go from there.

Comment: So... I can't possibly parse php error logs... ??

Comment: it's not a good idea, to parse logs, especially if you share your php environment with others. You should have your own error handlers, it is much more preferred and user friendly.

Comment: @MuhammedM. The admin dashboard would be only available to me... NO other user can access that. Thus there is no security issue...

Comment: it is still a good idea to have your own error handlers.

Comment: since php error log file is consistent, you dont have to do preg, just do substr, and extract date part, after what - the rest of the string is your error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit late but that's my solution (it supports stack traces too):

```
<?php

use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;

class ErrorLog {
    private $logFilePath;

    /**
     * ErrorLog constructor.
     *
     * @param string $logFilePath
     */
    public function __construct(string $logFilePath) {
        $this->logFilePath = $logFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * Parses the PHP error log to an array.
     *
     * @return \Generator
     */
    public function getParsedLogFile(): \Generator {
        $parsedLogs = [];
        $logFileHandle = fopen($this->logFilePath, 'rb');

        while (!feof($logFileHandle)) {
            $currentLine = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', fgets($logFileHandle));

            // Normal error log line starts with the date & time in []
            if ('[' === $currentLine[0]) {
                if (10000 === \count($parsedLogs)) {
                    yield $parsedLogs;
                    $parsedLogs = [];
                }

                // Get the datetime when the error occurred and convert it to berlin timezone
                try {
                    $dateArr = [];
                    preg_match('~^\[(.*?)\]~', $currentLine, $dateArr);
                    $currentLine = str_replace($dateArr[0], '', $currentLine);
                    $currentLine = trim($currentLine);
                    $errorDateTime = new DateTime($dateArr[1]);
                    $errorDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
                    $errorDateTime = $errorDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $errorDateTime = '';
                }

                // Get the type of the error
                if (false !== strpos($currentLine, 'PHP Warning')) {
                    $currentLine = str_replace('PHP Warning:', '', $currentLine);
                    $currentLine = trim($currentLine);
                    $errorType = 'WARNING';
                } else if (false !== strpos($currentLine, 'PHP Notice')) {
                    $currentLine = str_replace('PHP Notice:', '', $currentLine);
                    $currentLine = trim($currentLine);
                    $errorType = 'NOTICE';
                } else if (false !== strpos($currentLine, 'PHP Fatal error')) {
                    $currentLine = str_replace('PHP Fatal error:', '', $currentLine);
                    $currentLine = trim($currentLine);
                    $errorType = 'FATAL';
                } else if (false !== strpos($currentLine, 'PHP Parse error')) {
                    $currentLine = str_replace('PHP Parse error:', '', $currentLine);
                    $currentLine = trim($currentLine);
                    $errorType = 'SYNTAX';
                } else if (false !== strpos($currentLine, 'PHP Exception')) {
                    $currentLine = str_replace('PHP Exception:', '', $currentLine);
                    $currentLine = trim($currentLine);
                    $errorType = 'EXCEPTION';
                } else {
                    $errorType = 'UNKNOWN';
                }

                if (false !== strpos($currentLine, ' on line ')) {
                    $errorLine = explode(' on line ', $currentLine);
                    $errorLine = trim($errorLine[1]);
                    $currentLine = str_replace(' on line ' . $errorLine, '', $currentLine);
                } else {
                    $errorLine = substr($currentLine, strrpos($currentLine, ':') + 1);
                    $currentLine = str_replace(':' . $errorLine, '', $currentLine);
                }

                $errorFile = explode(' in /', $currentLine);
                $errorFile = '/' . trim($errorFile[1]);
                $currentLine = str_replace(' in ' . $errorFile, '', $currentLine);

                // The message of the error
                $errorMessage = trim($currentLine);

                $parsedLogs[] = [
                    'dateTime'   => $errorDateTime,
                    'type'       => $errorType,
                    'file'       => $errorFile,
                    'line'       => (int)$errorLine,
                    'message'    => $errorMessage,
                    'stackTrace' => []
                ];
            } // Stack trace beginning line
            else if ('Stack trace:' === $currentLine) {
                $stackTraceLineNumber = 0;

                while (!feof($logFileHandle)) {
                    $currentLine = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', fgets($logFileHandle));

                    // If the current line is a stack trace line
                    if ('#' === $currentLine[0]) {
                        $parsedLogsLastKey = key($parsedLogs);
                        $currentLine = str_replace('#' . $stackTraceLineNumber, '', $currentLine);
                        $parsedLogs[$parsedLogsLastKey]['stackTrace'][] = trim($currentLine);

                        $stackTraceLineNumber++;
                    } // If the current line is the last stack trace ('thrown in...')
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        yield $parsedLogs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own Exception and Error handler in PHP, this way users won't see errors and instead you could provide them with a nice error message informing them that something went wrong.

```
//Exception Handler
function my_exception_handler($exception) {
    echo "<p>App Exception {" , $exception->getMessage(), "}</p>\n";
}
\set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');
//Error handler
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo '<p style="color:darkred">App Error {'.$errno.', '.$errstr.'}</p>'."\n";
}
\set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
```

you can remove "\" in the beginning of the set_error_.. functions if you are not using any namespaces, or you can leave it, it ensures your code works from a custom namespace.

Customize those echo statements inside functions, do DB save, or simply use PHP's error_log function there to save your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, weirdly enough I found a way to do this, I do not know if it is the best way to do this... But the important thing is that it works...

So what I did was to remove the parts of string like the date and the `ERROR_TYPE`  once I parsed and stored them... And at the end we would be left with the error message...

**Update:**

> *Added returning json and xml objects of the errors

So this was my final class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: toton
 * Date: 2/29/2016
 * Time: 8:16 AM
 */

/**
 * Class error_parser
 * Members:
 * @param $log_file_path - private
 * @param $current_line - private
 * @param $recent - private
 * @param $errors_array - private
 *
 * Methods:
 * @method \__construct() - public
 * @method \_parse() - private
 *
 * Function:
 * TO parse the PHP ERROR LOG and provide a readable and a programmable array, consisting of the errors!
 */
final class error_parser
{
    private $log_file_path;
    private $current_line;
    private $recent;
    private $errors_array = array();

    /**
     * error_parser constructor.
     * Takes in the path of the error log file of PHP ERROR LOG FILE.
     * And another param for checking to get the direction to traverse the file.
     * @param string $log_file_path
     * @param bool $recent
     */
    public function __construct($log_file_path, $recent = true)
    {
        $this->log_file_path = $log_file_path;
        $this->recent = $recent;
        $this->_parse();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Parses the PHP ERROR LOG, and pushes an array with the following structure:
     * array(
     * "date" => {DATE},
     * "severity" => {SEVERITY},
     * "message" => {message},
     * "stack_trace" => array(each({STACK_TRACE})) || false;
     * );
     * to the main array.
     * !!!! IMPORTANT !!!!
     * STACK TRACE IS NOT SUPPORTED AT THIS MOMENT
     * TODO: IMPLEMENT STACK TRACE
     * MILESTONE: NEXT_MAJOR RELEASE
     */
    private function _parse() {
        $contents = file_get_contents($this->log_file_path);
        if(!$contents){
            throw new Exception("Log file does not exist.", 2);
        }
        $lines = explode("\n", $contents);
        if($this->recent) {
            $lines = array_reverse($lines);
        }
        for($this->current_line = 0; $this->current_line < count($lines); $this->current_line++) {
            parse_loop:
            $current_line = trim($lines[$this->current_line]);
            if(strlen($current_line) == 0) {
                //If the line is empty throw it to the dustbin.
                // SORRY, FOR THE GOTO.
                // GOD PLEASE FORGIVE ME!
                $this->current_line = $this->current_line + 1;
                goto parse_loop;
            }
            if($current_line[0] != "[") {
                // NOT SUPPORTING STACK TRACES AT THE MOMENT
                $this->current_line = $this->current_line + 1;
                goto parse_loop;
            }
            $dateArr = array();
            preg_match('~^\[(.*?)\]~', $current_line, $dateArr);
            $current_line = str_replace($dateArr[0], "", $current_line);
            $current_line = trim($current_line);
            $date = array(
                "date" => explode(" ", $dateArr[1])[0],
                "time" => explode(" ", $dateArr[1])[1]
            );
            $severity = "";
            if(strpos($current_line, "PHP Warning") !== false) {
                $current_line = str_replace("PHP Warning:", "", $current_line);
                $current_line = trim($current_line);
                $severity = "WARNING";
            } elseif(strpos($current_line, "PHP Notice") !== false) {
                $current_line = str_replace("PHP Notice:", "", $current_line);
                $current_line = trim($current_line);
                $severity = "NOTICE";
            } elseif(strpos($current_line, "PHP Fatal error") !== false) {
                $current_line = str_replace("PHP Fatal error:", "", $current_line);
                $current_line = trim($current_line);
                $severity = "FATAL";
            } elseif(strpos($current_line, "PHP Parse error") !== false) {
                $current_line = str_replace("PHP Parse error:", "", $current_line);
                $current_line = trim($current_line);
                $severity = "SYNTAX_ERROR";
            } else {
                $severity = "UNIDENTIFIED_ERROR";
            }
            $message = $current_line;
            /* Final Array *//* Add nodes while creating them */
            $finalArray = array(
                "date" => $date,
                "severity" => $severity,
                "message" => $message
            );
            array_push($this->errors_array, $finalArray);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function for returning the the error things in JSON format.
     * @return string <JSON STRING>
     */
    public function returnJson() {
        return json_encode($this->errors_array);
    }

    public function returnXml() {
        var_dump($this->errors_array);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><errors></errors>");
        $this->_array_to_xml($xml, $this->errors_array);
        // By this time we would get a xml "STRING"
        return $xml->asXML();
    }

    /* Factory Function */
    /**
     * Converts an array to an xml-dcument
     * @param $data
     * @param $xml_data <SimpleXMLObject>
     */
    private function _array_to_xml(&$xml_data, $data) {
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
            if( is_array($value) ) {
                if(is_numeric($key)){
                    $key = 'item' . $key;
                }
                $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                $this->_array_to_xml($subnode, $value);
            } else {
                $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```